# run django from ssh

Tags: python, django, bash, ssh

i want to create a django project using ssh, my host give me some options when i enable ssh, i'm allowed to use bash, zsh, ksh, csh,fish and tcsh, I'm familiar with bash but not with the rest so which is better for django? which is the closest to python? or are they all the same when it comes to application development?

Comment: Django really doesn't care what shell you are using, as far as I know. `bash` is fine.

Comment: The suggested model for django project is that you develop your project on a local computer and deploy on a server. The question does not say if you really understand the difference between these two.

Comment: When I am away from my computer for any reason (for example at my gf house) I just connect via ssh to my computer and program everything with vim, It really doesn't make a difference at all which shell you are using.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa i know that normally you should develop it on your pc and upload it, but i wanted to see if it works directly from the shell

Comment: FWIW I do almost all of my django programming over ssh using bash and vi. I'm not scared of command line and vi, I actually prefer to develop right on my server so I don't have to deal with the differences between databases, dependencies, and so forth. But maybe I'm not doing it "right"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chosen UNIX shell does not matter for the Python development. AFAIK the only shell specific part in Python development, which is currently being widely used, is virtualenv and it should work with sh compatible shells.